# LLDB and setSelectedViewController: "incompatible types"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, lldb

I put a breakpoint in my class that extends UITabBarController in `setSelectedViewController:`

```
(lldb) po selectedViewController
error: instance variable '_afterAppearance' declared with incompatible types in different translation units ('__block_literal_generic *' vs. '__block_literal_generic *')
note: declared here with type '__block_literal_generic *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Any idea what's going on? iOS 8.0, iOS SDK 8.3.

Comment: Intriguing, but if your code is not misbehaving it's unwise to worry very much about the niceties of lldb's often strange behavior.